# Extend phpmailer class

Tags: php, class, phpmailer

I am sending emails via *phpmailer* and I want to override the exceptions as when you send an email and that fails you can have the error message **Service Closing transmission error.**
can you help me.

```
 <?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    require 'sendmail/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    class MyPHPMailer extends PHPMailer{
    
        public function __construct($exceptions, $body = ''){
            
            parent::__construct($exceptions);
            
            $this->setFrom('{}@yahoo.com', 'Mahi');
            
            $this->isSMTP();
            
            $this->Host = 'tls://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587';
            
            $this->msgHTML($body);
    
            $this->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    
            // $this->Debugoutput = static function ($str, $level) {
            //     echo "Debug level $level; message: $str\n";
            // };
        }
    
        public function send(){
            $this->Subject = '[Yay for me!] ' . $this->Subject;
            $r = parent::send();
            echo 'I sent a message with subject ' . $this->Subject;
            return $r;
        }
    }
    
        try {
            $mail = new myPHPMailer(true, '<strong>This is the message body</strong>');
            $mail->addAddress('{}@yahoo.com', 'John');
            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
            $mail->addAttachment(__FILE__, 'myPHPMailer.php');
            $mail->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught a ' . get_class($e) . ': ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Is there a specific issue in the code you've written so far?

Comment: _"you can have the error message Service Closing transmission error."_ - and what exactly would be the point of that? if you are trying to get a specific error message shown _in the frontend_, then you should rather implement some logic to translate the _code_ the exception gives you, into the desired phrasing.